# Why does this closed post does not show the target duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The post in question is [Software license not valid in my country; how to handle being asked to use it anyways?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/119885/73791)

I first edited and then answered the post. However, some time later I found a duplicate of such, and proceeded to VTC.

In the meantime, and before I VTC'd, other users also casted their votes. However, those were note dupe votes, but company-specific votes.

The post finally reached 5 votes, and became closed. The votes in the end seem to be 3 votes for company-specific, and 2 for duplicate... **but the target duplicate is not shown on the top of the post**, as in other cases I've seen. Instead, it just lists the company-specific one, and says which 3 users casted the vote (but mine and the other do not show up).

I wonder if this had something to do with the multiple VTC reasons. However, in the past I've seen posts closed for multiple reasons, but (IIRC) all of the reasons are displayed and not only the one with more votes.

*Anybody has an explanation for this?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For close reasons, the majority rules.  Duplicate links are only shown in the question body for duplicates or when there's an active duplicate close vote.

We could reopen it and close as duplicate instead, since those other close votes came in before the dupe was found.  The questions look a *little* different to me (though maybe not in a way that matters), so I'd like to see a little support for doing that before mod-hammering it.  Thoughts, everyone?

Comment: I think that the dupe is highly similar. Still the post was answerable and IMO company specific was not q valid close reason

Comment: I'm always of the opinion that if it is off-topic and closed for the wrong reason, to just leave it as closed, as it has the same effect. Duplicates are a little different, but if you have the link in the comments, users can still find the linked question even if it isn't in the title.

Comment: @DavidK yeah, but the thing is that comments are ephemeral, and if it was closed in part for being a dupe the way of preserving such link is for it to appear on the close reason.

Comment: @DarkCygnus True that they're ephemeral, though in actuality once a question is closed they almost never get touched. That being said, I know that if a question is linked in the comments it automatically gets added to the "Linked Questions" sidebar. I'm not sure if it stays there if the linking comment is deleted or not.